Skip-lists in Data Structure

no. of comparisons for deletion : 3
no. of comparison of search(77) : 7 (halt)
but in the given answer source, find 5, 10 respectively.
can anyone provide the correct answer with explanation .
I analyzed the given skip list and tried to manually delete the node "50" by updating the pointers in each level. I also attempted to count the number of comparisons required for the deletion and for searching "77" in the modified skip list. I expected to calculate the exact number of comparisons for both operations, but I'm unsure if my approach is correct and need clarification on the exact process for traversals and pointer updates

Counting exact numbers of comparisons requires a concrete algorithm implementation, because different implementations may vary in the exact number of comparisons. For example, the exact number of comparisons in quicksort depends on the fine details of how the partitioning is done. (Do you check for index overlap? Or do you use a sentinel comparison?) For skip lists, you can sometimes avoid a comparison by doing an extra pointer comparison, but it comes at a cost of extra code.

Say you are head of the skip list, you are given that list is sorted, however you cannot apply binary search here since memory allocation is not contagious, thus you will have to go over each element and compare linearly.
You will check first 4 Nodes, which are not equal to 50. When you iterate to next node, and Found 50 you can simply delete it (which don't require any checks)
By: previous.next = current.next;
And current.next.previous = previous (if it is double linked list),
Where previous points to Node just before the Node to be deleted which is pointed by current.
Resulting, chain of 50 will not be referenced by any variable thus get collected by Garbage Collector (Of your language).
Thus total 5 checks are done to remove 50.
Now 50 is already removed, then you will start iterating over the list again from the head, you encountered that at the Node number 10 you encountered value 79 which is greater than searching value 77, thus you become sure here that 77 is not present in the list (since list is sorted).
In order to check for 77, you have to make 10 comparisons.
